# Node.js cluster module dilemma

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, scaling

I understand what scaling is and what the node.js cluster module is supposed to do by taking advantage of the remaining cores to improve concurrency.

But here is my question: If I have a certain function to run at, lets say 6pm daily,  how do I prevent all 8 workers from running the function 8 times at 6pm instead of once?

Comment: I need an algorithm

Comment: if you are using nodejs in cluster mode then request will be sent to only one worker process, it is handled by master worker. I would suggest to create a cron job instead of normal cluster mode for doing periodic jobs.

Comment: @Aky_0788 its was cron job using node-scheduler

Comment: can you post sample code here ? I want to understand why you are using cluster mode with node-schedule ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set an interval in master process and pick a random worker to do the job every time. You can use `worker.send(message)` function to let the worker know about the new task.

Another way is to prepare an API method that your app exposes. This method will trigger task execution when received. To call this API method, you can use a regular cron. That way, your app will be aware of the work it does, but not of the schedule.